# Compliance-SearchAction -Purge (Office 365 Exchange)

Tags: office365, exchange-server

I am trying to purge (completely delete, not SoftDelete) a specific email using a Compliance Search inside Office 365's SCC.

The search produces a result that shows it has found the correct number of items (Can confirm this by previewing).

When connecting into Exchange SCC with Powershell and running the below command:

```
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Name" -Purge
```

It does not appear to do a full purge, only a "SoftDelete".
If I run

```
Get-ComplianceSearchAction -Identity "Name_purge" | Format-List
```

I get detailed information about the action, but the following line alerts me to that fact it only did a SoftDelete:

```
Results: : Purge Type: SoftDelete
```

Is this method supposed to support purging items completely? I find it strange if not, as Microsoft describe the compliance centre as being able to assist in removing sensitive emails and alike.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an old question but I reached it through a top link on Google so I thought I'd make sure anyone in the future doesn't have to go any further.

`-PurgeType SoftDelete` Is the only supported option when purging. It deletes the item but it is still recoverable though the `Recoverable Items` folder. To work around this you can either clear the folder manually (with something like `Search-Mailbox –identity <identity> –SearchDumpsterOnly –DeleteContent`) or you can set your retention time lower for a short period and then set it back after the items are cleared.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear there is a hard delete option.

```
New-ComplianceSearchAction -SearchName "Remove Phishing Message" -Purge -PurgeType HardDelete
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/securitycompliance/search-for-and-delete-messages-in-your-organization).